# Create minio docker image with content

Tags: docker, minio

I would like to build a minio docker container for integration test purposes.

I would like to do the following in my Dockerfile.

- Create the minio container
- Create a test bucket
- Copy a small amount of test data into a test bucket
- Start the minio service

Test Data

```
./test-data/foo.txt
./test-data/bar.txt
```

```
FROM minio/minio

RUN mkdir -p /buckets/my-bucket 

COPY test-data /buckets/my-bucket/test-data"

EXPOSE 9000 9001

CMD [ "minio", "server", "/buckets", "--address", ":9000", "--console-address", ":9001" ]
```

I know that I could run `mc` in a separate container to populate my bucket, but that requires a little bit of orchestration.

Is there a way that I could accomplish these steps in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Dockerfile is just a collection of shell commands...so you can do pretty much anything you want. For example:

```
FROM docker.io/minio/minio:latest

COPY --from=docker.io/minio/mc:latest /usr/bin/mc /usr/bin/mc
RUN mkdir /buckets
RUN minio server /buckets & \
    server_pid=$!; \
    until mc alias set local http://localhost:9000 minioadmin minioadmin; do \
        sleep 1; \
    done; \
    mc mb local/bucket1; \
    echo this is file1 | mc pipe local/bucket1/file1; \
    echo this is file2 | mc pipe local/bucket1/file2; \
    kill $server_pid

CMD ["minio", "server", "/buckets", "--address", ":9000", "--console-address", ":9001"]
```

If we use the above Dockerfile to build an image named `minio-demo`, and then start a container like this:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 127.0.0.1:9000:9000 -p 127.0.0.1:9001:9001  minio-demo
```

We see:

```
$ mc alias set demo http://localhost:9000 minioadmin minioadmin
$ mc ls demo
[2022-07-07 22:01:35 EDT]     0B bucket1/
$ mc ls demo/bucket1
[2022-07-07 22:01:35 EDT]    14B STANDARD file1
[2022-07-07 22:01:35 EDT]    14B STANDARD file2
```

Comment: There are lots of great techniques in here.  Thank you!